# Is There A Way To Clean Up The Coding, Center Images & Make Things Stay In Place

Tags: html, css

Is There A Way To Clean Up The Coding, Center Images & Make Things Stay In Place..

Here Is The Look I Want..
Main Outer Box To Stay Centered Of The Browser Page..
Pause, Play & Stop Buttons To Float Left Of The Box..
Have My Image to Set In The Center Of The Box..
Add/Download Button To Float Right Of The Box..
Here Is A Demo Of What I Have So Far..
Click The Link [CountryDum Productions](http://cdp.x10host.com/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="box-set2">
      <audio id="player" src="audio/SUKA.mp3"></audio>
    <div>
      <button class="alignleft" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">
      <img src="images/Set1/pause.png" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
      </button>
      <button class="alignleft" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">
      <img src="images/Set1/play.png" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
      </button>
      <button class="alignleft" id="player" onclick="player.src = ''; player.src = 'audio/SUKA.mp3';">
      <img src="images/Set1/stop.png" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
      </button>
      <button class="alignright" onclick="window.location.href='download/TakeOne.rar'">
      <img src="images/Set1/add.png" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
      </button>
      <div id="image">
      <img src="images/kit.png" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
    </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<style>
.box-set2 {
background: #eaeaed;
height: 200px;
width:40%;
top:100px;
margin:0px 0px 20px 40%;
padding:10px;
position: relative;
}
.alignleft {
background: #eaeaed;
float: left;
border:0px;
margin-left: 2px;
padding: 0;
outline: 0;
}
.alignright {
background: #eaeaed;
float: right;
border:0px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#image {
border:0px;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set the background image for the button to the image that you want. This entails inline CSS in style tags. I assume you allow inline CSS?

Comment: I've Fixed The Post But I'm Having Issues Getting Things To Set Right & To Stay In Place.. Here's A Demo Of What I'm Working On.. http://cdp.x10host.com/                I Want The Box-Set To Stay Centered And I Want The Image To Also Stay Centered In The Box-Set.. I Want Everything To Stay Centered Except The Buttons.. Those Are Working Fine..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`background-image`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) instead `img` inside `button`

```css
button{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-image:url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/579/579268.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="audio/SUKA.mp3"></audio>
<div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>

<button id="player" onclick="player.src = ''; player.src = 'audio/SUKA.mp3';">Stop</button>
</div>
```

**Edit** combaine all buttons to one you must use JS and set `display:none/block` to button:

```js
function func(elem,id){
elem.style.display="none";
var elemShow=document.getElementById(id);
console.log()
elemShow.style.display="block";
}
```

```css
    button{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/579/579268.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    #pause,#play{
    display:none;
    }
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="audio/SUKA.mp3"></audio>
<div>
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play();func(this,'pause')" id="play">Play</button>
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause();func(this,'play')" id="pause">Pause</button>
 <button id="stop" onclick="func(this,'play');player.src = ''; player.src = 'audio/SUKA.mp3';">Stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: instead the play button ?

Comment: Don't think it's possible without some JavaScript to hide and show the individual buttons.

Comment: use `onclick=";player.src = ''; player.src = 'audio/SUKA.mp3';func(this,'play')"`

Comment: I need your explaination to understand do you want always show stop button and only `play/pause` change??

Comment: I've Fixed The Post But I'm Having Issues Getting Things To Set Right & To Stay In Place.. Here's A Demo Of What I'm Working On.. http://cdp.x10host.com/                I Want The Box-Set To Stay Centered And I Want The Image To Also Stay Centered In The Box-Set.. I Want Everything To Stay Centered Except The Buttons.. Those Are Working Fine..